# Building Mei's ice wall on top of another one

Tags: overwatch

In overwatch, Mei can build an ice wall. Let's say that there's more than one Mei's in a team, is it possible to build another ice wall on top of an ice wall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, ice walls do not stack on each other, regardless if it is an enemy Mei's Ice Wall or an ally's.